# Same code working on Arduino IDE but not in PlatformIO IDE

Tags: arduino-ide, c++, esp32, platformio

I'm running into this weird problem. My code is working just fine when I upload it to an ESP32 from Arduino IDE. That same code is not working when I upload it using PlatformIO IDE. The same libraries versions are being used on both environments.

I've been reading that in PlatformIO you might have to make use of forward declaration (something that Arduino IDE solves out of the box). I do not know if this is the case. And if it is... I do not know how to apply it.

Can someone help me out with this?

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <DHT.h>
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

#define DHTPIN 23
#define DHTTYPE DHT11

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,16,2);

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

void setup() {
  
  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();

  Serial.begin(115200);
  dht.begin();
}

void loop() {
  delay(2000);
  float h = dht.readHumidity();
  float t = dht.readTemperature();

  if (isnan(h) || isnan(t)) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed to read from DHT sensor!"));
    return;
  }

  Serial.print(F("Humedad: "));
  Serial.print(h);
  Serial.print(F("% Temperatura: "));
  Serial.print(t);
  Serial.println(F("°C "));

  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Humedad: ");
  lcd.println(String(h));
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Temp.: ");
  lcd.print(String(t));
}
```

EDIT:

platformio.ini

```
[env:fm-devkit]
platform = espressif32
board = fm-devkit
framework = arduino
monitor_speed = 115200
upload_port = COM9
lib_deps = 
    adafruit/DHT sensor library@^1.4.3
    adafruit/Adafruit Unified Sensor@^1.1.5
    marcoschwartz/LiquidCrystal_I2C@1.1.2
```

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean here? Do you get compilation errors? Or uploading errors? Or is the behavior of the code different than expected after successfull compilation and upload?

Comment: can you post your platformio.ini file? The problem could be that you are using a different version of the ESP-IDF which is pre-compiled in the arduino environment (which is not neccessarily the case when working with platformio).

Comment: @chrisl The code just compiles and runs... but it does not print anything to the display

Comment: @SimSon I added the plaformio.ini

Comment: hmm, the .ini looks like I'd expect it, except that I don't know that board (I assume that you'd choose the exact same board in the Arduino IDE). Maybe you could try to use `board=esp32dev` in case the pin mapping is messed up some how for that board (the pin mapping should not depend very much on the actual board as long as it's based on an ESP32. But that's my only idea here and I'm actually not sure if that makes much sense...

Comment: does not work either... thanks anyway

Comment: Does the code print to the serial monitor as expected? Could you try removing the “°” character in `F("°C ")`? Could you try removing the casts to `String` (`lcd.println(h);` instead of `lcd.println(String(h));`, same for `t`)?

Comment: And what is on the serial interface? (You can always add more trace messages to figure out how far it gets)

Comment: yes it does print to the serial monitor as expected

Comment: Verbose compile and link output for both environments might be of some use.